# Hart1´s Ruby Tutorial - Subl Gemfile - failed with error -43

Tags: ruby, gemfile

I am struggeling my way through Hart1's Ruby Tutorial, and I can't get past this point; whenever I execute the subl Gemfile command, I get the following error:

FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app) failed with error -43.

Can someone help me??

Comment: It's always better to include as much information as possible about your environment. What system and version?  What version of Sublime?  Is it installed and operational in other cases and only failing here?  I see that FSPathMakeRef has been deprecated in OS X, but that doesn't necessarily mean it should fail outright.  So, it would help to have quite a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

To echo what R_G said - you should definitely include more information about your environment to get better help.

What's happening here could be that you don't have sublime text installed in your applications (if you downloaded on a mac, you have to drag it into the applications folder - Or you don't have the 'subl' command set up in your command line. I never got subl as a command to work from my command line when I was working on a windows computer....

Here are instructions on how to do these things - if you are working from a Mac. http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

What it's trying to get you to do is just open the gemfile with sublime text - so since you are just beginning -- just do that. Manually open the sublime text application and then manually find the gem file in your application folders and open it.